# jdbcType=BIGDECIMAL not supported in mybatis and ibatis

Tags: jdbc, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

Using `jdbcType=BIGDECIMAL` is not supported in `myBatis` and `ibatis` and  is throwing the next error:

```
Error resolving JdbcType. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No enum constant org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType.BIGDECIMAL
```

What is the `jdbcType` alternative instead of `BIGDECIMAL`?

I'm using `mybatis-3.4.4` version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's happen because `BIGDECIMAL` jdbc type doesn't exist. Just take a look the enum `JdbcType` of `org.apache.ibatis.type`.

You should use `DECIMAL`.

---

The list of JdbcTypes available in `JdbcType enum`:

```
ARRAY(2003),
BIT(-7),
TINYINT(-6),
SMALLINT(5),
INTEGER(4),
BIGINT(-5),
FLOAT(6),
REAL(7),
DOUBLE(8),
NUMERIC(2),
DECIMAL(3),
CHAR(1),
VARCHAR(12),
LONGVARCHAR(-1),
DATE(91),
TIME(92),
TIMESTAMP(93),
BINARY(-2),
VARBINARY(-3),
LONGVARBINARY(-4),
NULL(0),
OTHER(1111),
BLOB(2004),
CLOB(2005),
BOOLEAN(16),
CURSOR(-10),
UNDEFINED(-2147482648),
NVARCHAR(-9),
NCHAR(-15),
NCLOB(2011),
STRUCT(2002),
JAVA_OBJECT(2000),
DISTINCT(2001),
REF(2006),
DATALINK(70),
ROWID(-8),
LONGNVARCHAR(-16),
SQLXML(2009),
DATETIMEOFFSET(-155);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using below type handler I have resolved my same issue:

```
<insert id=".......">
INSERT INTO demo (number_of_cities)
VALUES( #{numberOfCities, typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.BigDecimalTypeHandler});
</insert>
```